# Windows 10 Virtual Desktop - two inputs at the same time (mouse + touch screen)

Tags: wpf, touchscreen, virtual-desktop, virtual-screen, windows-virtual-desktop

I try to create WPF application (.net Core 3.1) with support touch screen and non-touch screen with two inputs at the same time.

I found a sample how to do this with VWvare and Virtual maschine [here is the sample](https://www.geckoandfly.com/23654/virtual-desktop-software-multiple-users/),
but I want to do something easier and without install 3rd party software.

I want to do something similar to the situation in the bank. The employee is working on the computer and the customer is "playing" with the app on the touch screen.

I have created two application parts (two separate Windows), 1. for main screen and 2. for touch screen.

The problem occurs when a customer clicks on their screen, so he takes the focus from the employee's screen.

I think this is a window setup rather than an application. I created Virtual Desktop, but it does not work separately input on touch screen. It always steals focus from the main screen.
Please how to make an two independent inputs into the application window?

Answer (score 0):

Create new instance of your window and than assign DataContext from original window

```
var viewModel = _container.Resolve<IViewModel>()

Window win1 = new Window();
win1.DataContext=viewModel;
win1.Show();
//move window to 1st screen

Window win2 = new Window();
win2.DataContext=win1.DataContext;
win2.Show();
//move window to 2nd screen
```

Comment: Hi @Anton, thanks for your reply, but I need to work with separate context. The customer will work from their View, fill out the form (radio button and checkboxes via touch screen), and the employee will prepare other things. I need these two activities not to affect each other.

Comment: So you want that operator and customer will type text concurently? I think it is not possible under one user in windows. But you can manage access customer to his customer screen via adding some transparent layer (with IsFocusable=false and bind Visibility={Binding IsCustomerScreenLocked, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter)}

Comment: Yes it should be possible, I've seen it before. But I just want a touch screen, not a keyboard. The employee will work normally with his keyboard and mouse, and the customer will just clicking through the touch screen.